# Number of complex roots of the equation $x^n=a, a\ge 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

> I have a question about number of complex roots of the equation
> $$x^n=a, a\ge 0, n\not\in \mathbb Z.$$

According to the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra if $x^n=a, n\in\mathbb N$, then we have exactly $n$ distinct complex roots. The real root is $x=\sqrt [n]{a}$, if $n$ is odd or $x_{1,2}=\pm \sqrt [n]{a}$, if $n$ is even.

But, when $n$ is not a natural number, for instance,

$$x^{\pi}=a, a\ge 0$$

What are all the complex roots and exactly how many roots are there?

I think that, $x=a^{\frac 1\pi}, a\ge 0$ is an only real root.

Comment: "The real root is only $x=\sqrt [n]{a}$." No, take $n=2$ and $a=4$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Fixed.

Comment: $x^{\pi}$ is not really well-defined if $x$ isn't a positive real. You can take it to mean $e^{\pi \log x}$ but then its value depends on a choice of branch of the logarithm. (I'm not saying anything here about how many different values of $x$ there are for a given value of $x^{\pi}$; I am saying that already to define the *function* one runs into multiple values.)

Comment: I agree with @QiaochuYuan ... Before asking about complex roots of the equation $x^n=a$ (for non-integer $n$), you first need to know a definition of $x^n$ (for non-integer $n$).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Cann't we say $x^{\pi}$ is well-defined in complex number set, when $x≤0$? Because, I am aware $(-1)^{\pi}$ is a non-real complex number.

Answer (score 1):

Coincidentally I was checking this out a few months back. I'll share my findings.

The roots of said function lie along the unit circle scaled up by $a^{\frac1n}$. I'll invert your expression into $\dfrac{1}{x^n-a}$ with $a> 0$ and make all of its roots poles instead to make everything much more obvious

For an integer power $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, we will get the $n$ roots of unity. The function is entire with no branch cut.

For each noninteger $n\in\mathbb{R}$, we have the number of poles will be the nearest odd integer. There will be a branch cut since by definition $$p(z) = z^c = \exp\left(c \ln(z)\right) = \exp\left(c \left( \operatorname{Log}(z) + 2n\pi i \right)\right),\qquad n\in \mathbb Z$$ and since $c$ is not a whole multiple of the logarithm, there will be multiple branches. We can safely choose it to be along the negative real axis.

We may observe that at $n=1$, we have a singular pole at $z=1$.

As we gradually increase our $n$, the pole splits into two along the branch cut and proceeds to make its way towards the positive real axis.

More generally, at every even integer, a pole appears at $\sqrt[n]{a}$ (which we will define to be the negative real pole), and as you increase $n$ the pole splits and pushes the other poles backwards along the unit circle scaled up by $a$ until we reach the next integer, where the poles would be at some arrangement of the roots of unity again.

In your example, we have $x^\pi=a$. The nearest odd number to this is $3$ so there will be $3$ poles, one at the positive real value of $a^{\frac1{\pi}}$ and the other two roots using the complex power function definition shared earlier would be at $a^{\frac1{\pi}}\cdot e^{2i}$ and $a^{\frac1{\pi}}\cdot e^{-2i}$, pretty close to the true third roots of unity since well, $\pi$ is close to $3$.

In the most general case(you can derive this too by tinkering with the logarithm definition of the power function), the solutions can be found as follows. Given $$x^n=a$$ our real root is $$a^{\frac{1}{n}}$$ Next, the complex roots will have this form... $$a^{\frac{1}{n}}\cdot e^{\pm\frac{(2u)\pi i}{n}}$$ for some $u\in\mathbb{N}$ given that the root you get from it will not violate your chosen argument(which in this case I selected $-\pi\le\arg(z)<\pi$).

You can use the manipulate command in mathematica to watch how the roots evolve, it is pretty fun. Here, I will let $a=2$ and show the pole evolution of $n$ from $n=2$ to $n=4$

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]